# Python switch function variant: Keys lambda functions

Tags: python, dictionary, lambda, switch-statement

I am working on a simple mapping problem where I have a value where its value falls in a given range, and that range determines the associated label. It is a typical sort of if/else problem, but I was wondering if I could use a dictionary to do the mapping, putting the lambda on the key side.

```
mapping = {
 lambda x: x >=1 and x <= 3590:'management',
 lambda x: x >= 3600 and x <= 4690:  'service',
 lambda x: x >= 4700 and x <= 5990:  'sales',
 lambda x: x >= 6000 and x <= 7690:  'natl recs/constr/maint',
 lambda x: x >= 7700 and x <= 9790:  'product/transp',
 lambda x: x >= 9800 and x <= 9830:  'milit'
}
```

but `mapping[2]`, for example, returns a key error, so it seems this is not kosher. Is the series of if/else statements the best way to go here?

Update:

The below version is simpler and more concise than the one above.

```
def mapping(x):
    if x >=1 and x <= 3590: y= 'management'
    if x >= 3600 and x <= 4690: y= 'service'
    if x >= 4700 and x <= 5990: y= 'sales'
    if x >= 6000 and x <= 7690: y= 'natl recs/constr/maint'
    if x >= 7700 and x <= 9790: y= 'product/transp'
    if x >= 9800 and x <= 9830: y= 'milit'
    return y
mapping(5556)
```

Comment: why are you using all `if's`? also `if 9800 <= x <= 9830` is the same as your current if check.

Comment: remember that in python you could do `if 1 <= x <= 3590`. I agree that the second one is simpler, is there a question yet to be asked here?

Comment: You can do this the way you want by subclassing `dict` and defining a new `__getitem__`, but it's not exactly elegant. I'll write something up as time allows

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to go at this IMHO would be:

```
def mapping(x):
    if 1 <= x <= 3590: return 'management'
    if 3600 <= x <= 4690: return  'service'
    if 4700 <= x <= 5990: return  'sales'
    if 6000 <= x <= 7690: return  'natl recs/constr/maint'
    if 7700 <= x <= 9790: return  'product/transp'
    if 9800 <= x <= 9830: return  'milit'
```

Your suggested methods does redundant checks. If you're using `if`s and storing the result in `y` instead of returning immediately, you check all of the conditions even if you were successful on the first one (take 3000 for example). Here this isn't the case, but this could be written with a `y` and `elif`.

In addition your code will throw an exception for 3595 (while this one returns `None`)

Comment: `if` versus `elif` doesn’t matter when you’re using `return`.

Comment: Could have some impact of performance if use `x in range(1, 3590)` instead `if`s?

Comment: @MauroBaraldi of course - you're initializing a list of >3500 items with range. And `in` a list is O(n) vs. O(1) of a simple boolean operator.

Comment: @Korem note that in Python3, `range` creates a generator not a list so that impact is minimized. Still: the big O doesn't change :)

Answer (score 2):

I would use `elif`s, you don't need to check each `if` statement if the previous statement evaluates to `True` which is what is happening using all `if`s unless you `return`in each if statement.

```
def mapping(x):
    if 1 <= x <= 3590:
       return 'management'
    if 3600 <= x <= 4690:
       return 'service'
    if 4700 <= x <= 5990:
       return 'sales'
    if 6000 <= x <= 7690:
       return 'natl recs/constr/maint'
    if 7700 <= x <= 9790:
       return 'product/transp'
    if 9800 <= x <= 9830:
       return 'milit'
```

In your code you would use `elif's` and set y to a value to handle input not in any range

```
def mapping(x):
    y = None
    if x >=1 and x <= 3590: y= 'management'
    elif x >= 3600 and x <= 4690: y= 'service'
    elif x >= 4700 and x <= 5990: y= 'sales'
    elif x >= 6000 and x <= 7690: y= 'natl recs/constr/maint'
    elif x >= 7700 and x <= 9790: y= 'product/transp'
    elif x >= 9800 and x <= 9830: y= 'milit'
    return y
```

Comment: @Korem, I had already commented about using if's long before your answer ;)

Comment: Yea, definitely a joint effort :)

Answer (score 2):

You could do a few things to make that mapping work, but all of them are kind of gross. The least gross way (I suppose) would be to do something like:

If you REALLY want to do this with something that looks like item access, you can try this:

```
class MapToRange(dict):

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        try:
            super(MapToRange, self).__getitem__(item)
        except KeyError:
            for key in self:
                if item in key:
                    return self[key]
            else:
                raise

mapping = MapToRange({range(   1, 3591): 'management',
                      range(3600, 4691): 'service',
                      range(4700, 5991): 'sales',
                      range(6000, 7691): 'natl recs/constr/maint',
                      range(7700, 9791): 'product/transp',
                      range(9800, 9831): 'milit'})

>>> mapping[3500]
management
>>> mapping[0]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#53>", line 1, in <module>
    mapping[0]
  File "<pyshell#46>", line 4, in __getitem__
    return super(MapToRange, self).__getitem__(item)
KeyError: 0
```

Note that in Python2, this costs a lot of memory since `range` creates lists not iterators. Try `xrange` instead in Python2.

A slightly faster arrangement would be to specify validation functions for each key, and return the value attached to the first one that returns `True`. Note that results could be unexpected because `dict`s are unordered, so consider subclassing `OrderedDict` for this as so:

```
class MapToFunc(collections.OrderedDict):
    def __getitem__(self, item):
        try:
            super(MapToFunc, self).__getitem__(item)
        except KeyError:
            for key,value in self.items():
                if key(item):
                    return value
            else:
                raise

>>> mapping = MapToFunc([(lambda x:    1 <= x <= 3590, 'management'),
                         (lambda x: 3600 <= x <= 4690, 'service'),
                         (lambda x: 4700 <= x <= 5990, 'sales'),
                         (lambda x: 6000 <= x <= 7690, 'natl recs/const/maint'),
                         (lambda x: 7700 <= x <= 9790, 'product/transp'),
                         (lambda x: 9800 <= x <= 9830, 'milit')])
>>> mapping[3500]
management
>>> mapping[0]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#94>", line 1, in <module>
    mapping[0]
  File "<pyshell#90>", line 4, in __getitem__
    super(MapToFunc, self).__getitem__(item)
KeyError: 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `bisect_right` on a sorted list of boundaries might work:

```
from bisect import bisect_right

keys = [1, 3600, 4700, 6000, 7700, 9800]
values = ['management', 'service', 'sales', 'natl recs/constr/maint',
          'product/transp', 'milit']

print(values[bisect_right(keys, 5556)]) # natl recs/constr/maint
```

Comment: Should've been `values[bisect_right(keys,x)]`. But it's problematic at the OPs case, as he has a noncontinuous range - for example, he has to insert `None` for the range of (3590, 3600)

Comment: @Korem: Since they’re all multiples of 10, I don’t think any value in between is possible. (The OP’s existing code and ideal dictionary-thing would throw an error.)

Comment: @Korem: The gaps between the ranges are also 10.

Comment: This is a neat and concise solution when all values in the ranges are allowed.